# minimum number of jumps dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I wrote this code to solve a problem called minimum number of jumps which basically asks what are the minimum number of jumps it takes to get from the beginning of the array at `i=0` to the end of the array at `i = length of array - 1`.

The idea is that you can jump up to `a[i]` spaces or can choose to jump to a space less than `i + a[i]` and whichever you choose will be considered 1 jump.

Example:
`a = [3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 3]`

answer is 3 -> (4 or 2) -> (2 or 3) -> 7 -> 3

which then gives 4 jumps as an answer. I actually get 5 instead with my solution. I am not sure why I am not getting the minimum. First off I do not know if I am using the right approach but I figured a lot of dynamic programming problems are solved using a 2d array so I tried it and I figured I am very close to the solution but having some difficulty as to where I am wrong.

```
def minNumberOfJumps(array):
    minJumps = [[float('inf') for _ in range(len(array))]
                for _ in range(len(array))]

    for row in minJumps:
        row[0] = 0

    for col in range(1, len(minJumps[0])):
        if array[0] >= col:
            minJumps[0][col] = 1

    for row in range(1, len(minJumps)):
        jumpChanged = False
        for col in range(1, len(minJumps[row])):
            jump = array[row] + row

            if minJumps[row - 1][col] != float('inf'):
                minJumps[row][col] = minJumps[row - 1][col]
            elif not jumpChanged and jump <= col:
                minJumps[row][col] = minJumps[row - 1][col - 1] + 1
                jumpChanged = True
            elif jump >= col:
                minJumps[row][col] = minJumps[row][col - 1]

    return minJumps[-1][-1]
```

The idea behind my solution is I add `1` when I need to jump. Going to any index

say original array is a, then
`i <= i + a[i]`, consider it `1` jump, otherwise,
if we have reached an index `i`, where `i > i + a[i]` position is not reachable (i label it as infinity in 2d array `b`)

if we are looking at rows `1` up to the length of `b - 1` then we always check the minimum number of jumps it took us to get to the current position one row before at `b[i - 1][j]` and take that number. If that number is `infinity` and we can make a jump meaning current column, `j`, we are looking at is `j <= to i + a[i]` then we add `1` to the previous jump, `b[i - 1][j - 1]`. If we have tried making a jump already than I only update the other values for all other positions i can jump to with the value at `b[i][j - 1]`, or basically from the column before.

I believe I have explained this correctly but I do not know why I am not right with my way of thinking.

Comment: You should calculate `jumps_left` and work through the array from the right to the left.  This lets you start with the trivial solution, and fill in final answers at each step.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought of right to left but I would like to understand why my solution is not working. With my approach I believe that if I am at position `i` and I can make a jump of `a[i]` there is a case when it may take me `+1` steps compared to the previous minimum amount of steps it took me to get to position `i + (i...a[i])` in which case I would take the minimum of amount of steps: say  I had a 2d array, `minJumps` then `minJumps[i - 1][j]` will be the previous minimum. Shouldn't this logic be sound. I can see that it doesn't work but  makes sense. What am I not seeing?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that a change of one jump can affect what the right choice was earlier.  Therefore every time you find that `jumpChanged` you should be willing to recalculate all earlier decisions.  If you made it a double loop until no jump changed, then you'd get the right answer.  But this potentially requires a lot of recalculation.